# react-router how do I use redirectLocation or the 301 or 302 status

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, react-router, http-status-code-301

We are about to deploy our site in reactjs and we have (re)moved one url but merged it in our main page so from `/[product]/menu` we merged it to `/[product]`. Now they said I should respond with 301 for `/[product]/menu` and redirect it to `/[product]`, how do I accomplish that and some other pages as well?

How do I setup 301 redirects using react-router? Where do I setup what pages needs to be redirected to what other pages? I have my setup like this right now:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  // routes is our object of React routes defined above
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirectLocation, props) => {
    console.log(redirectLocation);
    if (err) { // something went badly wrong, so 500 with a message
      res.status(500).send(err.message);

    // HERE: HOW DO I USE THIS?
    } else if (redirectLocation) { // we matched a ReactRouter redirect, so redirect from the server
      console.log('301/302 yeah!');
      res.redirect(301, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);

...
```

I use reactjs and express as well.

*Edit* Added route config.

```
const routes = {
  path: '',
  component: AppComponent,
  childRoutes: [{
    path: '/products',
    component: ProductsComponent,
    name: 'products'
  }, {
    path: '/:slug',
    component: ProductComponent,
    name: 'product'
  }]
}
```

Just in case. Added answer here:

```
const routes = {
  path: '',
  component: AppComponent,
  childRoutes: [{
    path: '/products',
    component: ProductsComponent,
    name: 'products'
  }, {
    path: '/:slug',
    component: ProductComponent,
    name: 'product'
  }, { 
    path: '/:product/menu', onEnter(nextState, replace) { replace(`/${nextState.params.product}`) }
  }, {
    path: '/oldlink/:testId', onEnter(nextState, replace) { replace({pathname: `http://newsite.com/oldlink/some/${nextState.params.testId}`}) }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the routes declaration, use `<Redirect>`. [Example Here](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)

Comment: Thanks! If I have this setup how do I translate it to that example you gave? Updated my question to reflect my routes config.

Comment: I can see you post the solution. Good Job!

Comment: Thanks! Quick question again. How do I do an absolute path? It's saying `Warning: A path must be pathname + search + hash only, not a fully qualified URL like` when I write absolute path on replace.

Comment: Sorry jumped into asking already. Haha! Found the solution. Updating question just in case anyone bumps into this as well.

Comment: @index Be sure to include the 301 status in the redirect tag. It defaults to 302. EG <Redirect status={301} from="..." to="..." />

Comment: @SystemicPlural what does adding the status in the `Redirect` tag give you? It doesn't get passed to `redirectLocation` or `renderProps`. I'm trying to find out how to choose between `301` and `302`. I was hoping to use that trick but not finding any use for it :(

Comment: Since the accepted answer link is broken I want to note that when you're providing links to github, you can press "Y" and get the hash link for that file. Here's the relevant information https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/2189ab92be9d4deeb6b9756e4ee21ea0ba5ef28b/packages/react-router/docs/api/StaticRouter.md.


But to answer the question of 3xx redirects, that is completely determined by your server. The router will provide you a `url` within the `context` object which you can then decide what status code to use within your app as seen in my example link.